# Создание сложной поверхности по точкам

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

В качестве исходных данных имеется набор точек объекта в трёхмерном пространстве.
Заданы следующим образом.
Объект "разрезан" на множество слоёв. Каждый слой представляет собой набор точек записаны по порядку друг за другом с поворотом на определённый градус по оси z (понятно в каком порядке их соединять).

Разработку необходимо вести с использованием QT, дальше полная свобода.
Я нашёл информацию про QGL и начал двигаться в этом направлении. Уже построил координатные оси и научился строить всякие примитивы. Думаю в ближайшее время смогу построить и все эти точки, в том числе соединить их прямыми или поверхностями в виде треугольников.

**Однако требуется сделать "гладкую" поверхность. Подскажите функцию, которая может мне в этом помочь.**

Comment: наверное nurbs?

Comment: Где она реализована?

Comment: в том или ином виде они много где используются

Comment: Что посоветуете Вы? Конкретная библиотека. С учетом всего вышесказанного.